# does CSS absolute positioning mean don't use it?

Tags: css

I used with apprehension the position:absolute; in my container for my template so that I have the center and both sides placed.

However, as I feared, if you happen to want that your website is visited by someone else other than yourself, then don't use it. This is because absolute position means one thing for you and another thing for someone else with a different monitor screen with different dimensions, right?

I went to another computer to see my web and the box was displaced towards the right?

Am I right in what I am saying?

thank you

here are my containers

```
#container-center{
  width:630px; /*** Set to = center col width ***/
  height:500px;
  float:center;
  font-size:8px;
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
    left:450px;
    top:80px;

/* \*/
  margin-left:-1px;
/* Hidden from IE-mac */
}



#left_container_home{
  width:150px; /*** Set to = center col width ***/

  height:500px;

  font-size:8px;
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
    left:250px;
    top:80px;

/* \*/
  margin-left:-1px;
/* Hidden from IE-mac */
}


#right_container{
  width:200px; /*** Set to = center col width ***/

  height:500px;
  float:right;
  font-size:8px;
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
  left:1085px;
  background:#F3F3F4;
  top:80px;

/* \*/
  margin-left:-1px;
/* Hidden from IE-mac */

}
```

Would this technique be correct? what I have done I mean. I say it because, I dont see how saying "left 450 px " can be right for me and right for someone else with a smaller screen.

I have modified the header like this, and it has drifted to the left! why would it if I am just telling it margin 0 auto?

```
#header {


    background: url("../jq185/css/start/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_75_2191c0_500x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #2191C0;
    font-family: 'trebuchet ms',geneva,arial,tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    width: 930px; margin: 0 auto; 
    h2 {color:#ffffff;}



}
```

Comment: Edited my answer for the new question

Comment: You can use `position: absolute` at will, as part of W3C, when you use it for... Absolute positioning! What you should never use are these hacks for IE-Mac or wathever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, no. `position:absolute;` means it is *absolutely* positioned in a *relatively* positioned container. Take the following example:

```
x { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

This means it will be placed in the top left corner of it's parent container, if that has `position:relative;`. However, if it does not, it will keep travelling up the DOM tree, untill it finds one that does. If noone does, it will be placed in the top left corner of the document (`body`).

Read more on CSS positioning here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position
- http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/position
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html

In your specific example, I think you are looking to simply center something. The best way to achieve that, is not with `position: absolute;`, but with wrapping your content in a container with a set width, and apply auto margins, like so:

```
.wrap { width: 920px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

This means it has a fixed width, and use the share the remaining space on both sides equally as margin.

Comment: So, if it is the very outer most container ? it would be regarding the document therefore, it would look differently depending on the screen size, wouldn't it?

Comment: well, I am testing the application, here is my web and tell me how you people see it:  www.hrcprojectconsulting.com/index.php/home_c/

Comment: Correct. Absolute positioning would probably not make much sense if it is the first ancestor of `body`. It is however very useful, if you wish to offset something or make sure it always have the same position. Say you have some text on top of an image, and you want the it to always be offset 20px from the bottom right corner of the image. That would be a good usecase for absolute positioning, especially since the element taken out of the regular flow.

Comment: alright, that says it then. Hmm, I am going to have to change my containers then

Comment: I've updated the answer with a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I have just modified the CSS including this margin 0 auto, and the container has leaped out of the center of the screen to some radical place in the lower corner. :(

Answer (score 3):

No, absolute positioning has many uses. Everything in the css spec has its use and you should never say "don't use this". That being said, the positioning IS absolute and thus can be messed up if you don't do it properly. You need to use the right tools for the right situation, and use them correctly.

Edit in response to updated question:

NO. Do not use absolute positioning for that! All you're trying to do is have a div in the middle. This can be achieve by something as simple as `<div id="content"></div>` then `#content { width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;` and that will center it for literally everyone, with very little markup.

Comment: absolute positioning is handy but it shouldn't be used to make sure something sits in the centre. You should look at utilising other css properties to do that.

do you have any markup that we can look at to give you a better idea on what you should do?

Comment: The situation I used it is what I describe, I wanted to create my box containers for my content, so I created a 3 divs left, center and right and gave them absoulute positioning. I am going to write the code above.

Comment: Thank you everybody, I did not know how to center it.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning will position your element at the exact same screen offset across all browsers, no matter what the screen size. However, everything that you don't have absolutely position will adhere to the usual model and that will change depending on screen size, in many cases. What you are seeing is that relative to the other elements, your absolute positioned element is moving.

Any assumptions you made about screen size while using absolute positioning will be throw out once that changes.

Comment: Yes, if I say left:450px; yes it will set it to 450 to everybody but my screen has 17 inches, whilst others can be 15 or less, so 450 would shift it to the right,

Comment: ok, then both of you have the same answer, so I should have not used absolute positioning in the outer container. thank you. Now I have the same dilemma both deserve the correct answer. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

An element which is positioned absolutely is offset from its nearest positioned ancestor, that is an ancestor element which has position set to anything other than "static", or the document root element if no such positioned ancestor exists.

There are many useful reasons why you would do this. Centering content isn't normally one of them though, there are other methods for doing that.